# module 'smart_open' has no attribute 'local_file'

Tags: gensim

I have written this code

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a29f5eabd8f4> in <module>
     85 # use the following command in anaconda prompt with the admionistrator privileges to install gensim
     86 # conda install -c conda-forge gensim
---> 87 import gensim
     88 from gensim import corpora
     89 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py in <module>
      3 """
      4 
----> 5 from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
      6 import logging
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from .porter import PorterStemmer  # noqa:F401
----> 4 from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
      5                             strip_tags, strip_short, strip_numeric,
      6                             strip_non_alphanum, strip_multiple_whitespaces,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\preprocessing.py in <module>
     40 import glob
     41 
---> 42 from gensim import utils
     43 from gensim.parsing.porter import PorterStemmer
     44 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in <module>
     43 from six.moves import range
       44 
---> 45 from smart_open import open
     46 
     47 from multiprocessing import cpu_count

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\__init__.py in <module>
     26 from smart_open import version
     27 
---> 28 from .smart_open_lib import open, parse_uri, smart_open, register_compressor
     29 from .s3 import iter_bucket as s3_iter_bucket
     30 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py in <module>
     35 
     36 from smart_open import compression
---> 37 from smart_open import doctools
     38 from smart_open import transport
     39 from smart_open import utils

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\doctools.py in <module>
     19 
     20 from . import compression
---> 21 from . import transport
     22 
     23 PLACEHOLDER = '    smart_open/doctools.py magic goes here'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\transport.py in <module>
     20 NO_SCHEME = ''
     21 
---> 22 _REGISTRY = {NO_SCHEME: smart_open.local_file}
     23 
     24 

AttributeError: module 'smart_open' has no attribute 'local_file'
```

I have received the error : module 'smart_open' has no attribute 'local_file'
how can I solve it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you attempting this import in Jupyter Notebook, or something similar? See my comment on the answer by Amratha s, below.

Answer (score 5):

I make smart_open downgrading to 1.9.0
and make gensim downgrading to 3.4.0
it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me,

First, if `gensim` and `smart_open` have not been installed, it can be done using the following,

```
pip install gensim==3.4.0
pip install smart_open==1.9.0
```

After that, the packages can simply be imported,

```
import smart_open
import gensim
```

Make sure that you import `smart_open` first.

Comment: Thanks **Minura Punchihewa** it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem and upgrading version of **smart_open** helped

```
python -m pip install --upgrade smart_open
```

In case of conda, updating dependencies should do the trick

```
conda install -c anaconda --update-deps gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed gensim which had smart_open-1.11.1 and was facing the same issue. I am not sure if the latest version has some kind of bug or not but downgrading smart_open-1.11.1 to smart_open-1.9.0 worked.

Answer (score -1):

Got lost in same error for days..Finally the below worked

1. Open ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\transport.py in  on
   your editor
2. Go to Line 22, change _REGISTRY = {NO_SCHEME:
       smart_open.local_file} to "_REGISTRY = {NO_SCHEME:
       *smart_open_lib*.local_file}"
3. Add line import smart_open_lib in the start of file along with other imports

Comment: In 2.1.1, which is the latest version at the time of my writing, that doesn't work for me, since smart_open_lib aliases `smart_open.local file` as `so_file`.  I can code around that by rewriting the import (`from . import local_file`) and references in transport.py, but the bigger issue here is something screwy happening with relative imports: I only get the problem when importing `gensim` in Jupyter Notebook. I get a completely different issue (a failed autoreload of `six`) in Spyder's IPython console, and no error at all in a vanilla Python shell.

Comment: To comment on my own comment.....My problem apparently was trying to import gensim right after installing it, while Jupyter Notebook was running. Restarting Jupyter and Sypder fixed the problems with both environments.